# One of the values in a dynamically allocated array always prints a garbage value

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, garbage

Why is p[1].x printing out to a garbage value?
Is it possible to initialize a dynamically allocated array to a given array? If yes, then how?

```
#include <ioStream>
using namespace std;

struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
};
int N;
point *p = new point[N];
int main(){
    cin>>N;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        cin>>p[i].x>>p[i].y;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        cout<<"("<<p[i].x<<", "<<p[i].y<<")"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cyber, that deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On these two lines, you are sizing an array with a variable that is zero initialized (`N`).

```
int N;
point *p = new point[N];
```

Therefore, you would be `new`ing an array of length `0`. This would lead to problems once you `cin>>N` because you use that variable to loop and write to the array, which will be writing outside the allocated space.

These types of cases really beg for `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: `N` _is_ zero-initialised before `main`. That's because it has "static storage duration" by virtue of being a global.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behaviour because variable N was not initialized with the number of potential elements of the array when it was used to allocate the array in the heap

```
int N;
point *p = new point[N];
```

That is as a global variable with the static storage duration it was assigned 0 by the compiler. According to the C++ Standard

> When the value of the expression is zero, the allocation function is
>   called to allocate **an array with no elements.**

Rewrite your code at least like

```
#include <ioStream>
using namespace std;

struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(){
    int N;

    cin>>N;
    point *p = new point[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        cin>>p[i].x>>p[i].y;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        cout<<"("<<p[i].x<<", "<<p[i].y<<")"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum number of points, better do something like:

```
const int MAXN = 1000;
Point p[MAXN];

int N;
cin >> N;
// ...
```

You can manually allocate space as well but you should read N first.

```
cin >> N;
Point *p = new Point[N];
// ...
```

A third option is to use a container (`vector` for dynamic arrays).

```
vector<Point> p;
cin >> N;
while(N--)
{   int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    Point p_(x, y); // Assumes constructor exists
    p.push_back(p_);
}
```

Comment: The third option is new to me. p.push_back() is quite usefull, I can use that in other programs too. Thanks ..

Comment: You are welcome, you can use a reference to learn these things. Google cppreference. You can also vote up my answer if it did help :)